# Concatenate/Modify the array variable using loop

Tags: java, arrays

I was wondering since I used a lot of "sum" variable but with different index at the end, I would like to declare them in a loop so if I want to declare an array 10 time, I wouldn't have to do them one by one like this:

```
double sum1, sum2, sum3, sum4, sum5, ... sum10  = 0.0;
```

Instead, I can do it in a loop like this but I'm not sure how to concatenate into a variable:

```
 for (int i=0;i<10;i++)
   {
      clus[i] = 0.0;  //ofc these wouldn't work
      double (clus + i); 
   }
```

Can't find the way to do it anywhere so any help would be good. Thanks.

Comment: Why not define a `double[] sum = new double[10]` array?

Comment: You say *"I want to declare an array"*, so why not just ... declare an array ... like @Eran said?

Comment: Just thought if it would be possible since the program uses this kind of array declaration... If not then, i guess I would be using that.

Comment: It's impossible. Java is static language. Variable declaration happens at compile time. You can't do it at runtime.  And Java doesn't have a preprocessor like C does. Please just use array.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

An array is theoretically a collection of variables with the same data type. You can instantiate an array in one line

```
Datatype[] variableName = new Datatype[arraySize];
```

In your case it would look like

```
Double[] clus = new Double[10];
```

From there, after you've imported the java.util.Arrays, you can use fill which works the same way as a loop, but specifically for arrays (and requires less code).

```
Arrays.fill(arrayName, whatToFillItWithProvidedItsTheProperDataType);
```

At this point you should have an array with 10 indexes filled with a double of your choice.

How can you access an individual portion of the array?

```
arrayName[indexNumber]
```

If I wanted to change the value of the 5th element to 30 (for example)

```
arrayName[4] = 30;
```

Bear in mind that when dealing with arrays, 0 is considered an element and counts as an index.

Answer (score 0):

You can use :

```
double [] myarray = new double[10];
Arrays.fill(myarray, 0);
```

you can fill all of your array with any number ,
as you know the default value is 0.0 .